# How to extract Active domain

Tags: bash, curl, awk, grep, nslookup

Is there any bash command/script in Linux so we can extract the active domains from a long list,

example, I have a csv file (domains.csv) there are 55 million domains are listed horizontally, we need only active domains in a csv file (active.csv)

Here active mean a domain who has a web page at least, not a domain who is expired or not expired.  example whoisdatacenter.info is not expired but it has no webpage, we consider it as non-active.

I check google and stack website. I saw we can get domain by 2 ways. like

```
$ curl -Is google.com | grep -i location 
Location: http://www.google.com/

or 

nslookup google.com | grep -i name 
Name:   google.com
```

but I got no idea how can I write a program in bash for this for 55 million domains.

below commands, won't give any result so I come up that nsloop and curl is wayway to get result

```
$ nslookup whoisdatacenter.info | grep -i name 
$ curl -Is whoisdatacenter.info | grep -i location
```

1st 25 lines

```
$ head -25 domains.csv 

"
"0----0.info"
"0--0---------2lookup.com"
"0--0-------free2lookup.com"
"0--0-----2lookup.com"
"0--0----free2lookup.com"
"0--1.xyz"
"0--123456789.com"
"0--123456789.net"
"0--6.com"
"0--7.com"
"0--9.info"
"0--9.net"
"0--9.world"
"0--a.com"
"0--a.net"
"0--b.com"
"0--m.com"
"0--mm.com"
"0--reversephonelookup.com"
"0--z.com"
"0-0-0-0-0-0-0-0-0-0-0-0-0-0-0-0-0-0-0-0-0-0-0-0-0-0-0-0-0-0-0-0.com"
"0-0-0-0-0-0-0-0-0-0-0-0-0-0-0-0-0-0-0-0.com"
"0-0-0-0-0-0-0-0-0-0-0-0-0-10-0-0-0-0-0-0-0-0-0-0-0-0-0.info"
```

code I am running

```
while read line; 
do nslookup "$line" | awk '/Name/'; 
done < domains.csv > active3.csv
```

the result I am getting

```
 sh -x ravi2.sh 
+ read line
+ nslookup ''
+ awk /Name/
nslookup: '' is not a legal name (unexpected end of input)
+ read line
+ nslookup '"'
+ awk /Name/
+ read line
+ nslookup '"0----0.info"'
+ awk /Name/
+ read line
+ nslookup '"0--0---------2lookup.com"'
+ awk /Name/
+ read line
+ nslookup '"0--0-------free2lookup.com"'
+ awk /Name/
+ read line
+ nslookup '"0--0-----2lookup.com"'
+ awk /Name/
+ read line
+ nslookup '"0--0----free2lookup.com"'
+ awk /Name/
```

still, active3.csv is empty 
below . the script is working, but something stopping the bulk lookup, either it's in my host or something else.

```
while read line
do
nslookup $(echo "$line" | awk '{gsub(/\r/,"");gsub(/.*-|"$/,"")} 1') | awk '/Name/{print}'
done < input.csv >> output.csv
```

The bulk nslookup show such error in below

```
server can't find facebook.com\013: NXDOMAIN
```

[Solved]
Ravi script is working perfectly fine, I was running in my MAC which gave Nslookup Error, I work in CentOS Linux server, Nslookup work great with Ravi script

Thanks a lot!!

Comment: Wait, wait, there are `"55 million domains are listed horizontally,"` -- meaning per-line??

Comment: @david-c-rankin . 1 domain in 1 line.  i.e. 1 domain per line

Comment: Could you please confirm if you really have `0-`s in your file or it is just a sample?

Comment: domains are like xyz.com   0--b.com 0--9.world and so on .. example 0--0----free2lookup.com was booking long ago.. now its not active, but its in our file

Comment: @RavinderSingh13 

[Solved] Ravi script is working perfectly fine, I was running in my MAC which gave Nslookup Error, I work in CentOS Linux server, Nslookup work great with Ravi script

Thanks a lot!!

Comment: @Priyanka, very Happy that our 2 to 3 hours hard work paid off :) :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

***EDIT:*** Please try my EDIT solution as per OP's shown samples.

```
while read line
do
   nslookup $(echo "$line" | awk '{gsub(/\r/,"");gsub(/.*-|"$/,"")} 1') | awk '/Name/{found=1;next} found && /Address/{print $NF}'
done < "Input_file"
```

---

---

Could you please try following.

OP has control M characters in her Input_file so run following command too remove them first:

```
tr -d '\r' < Input_file > temp && mv temp Input_file
```

Then run following code:

```
while read line
do
   nslookup "$line" | awk '/Name/{found=1;next} found && /Address/{print $NF}'
done < "Input_file"
```

I am assuming that since you are passing domain name you need to get their address(IP address) in output. Also since you are using a huge Input_file so it may be a bit slow in providing output, but trust me this is a simpler way.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/204296/discussion-on-answer-by-ravindersingh13-how-to-extract-active-domain).

Answer (score 0):

`nslookup` simply indicates whether or not the domain name has a record in DNS. Having one or more IP addresses does not automatically mean you have a web site; many IP addresses are allocated for different purposes altogether (but might coincidentally host a web site for another domain name entirely!)

(Also, `nslookup` is not particularly friendly to scripting; you will want to look at `dig` instead for automation.)

There is no simple way to visit 55 million possible web sites in a short time, and probably you should not be using Bash if you want to. See e.g. https://pawelmhm.github.io/asyncio/python/aiohttp/2016/04/22/asyncio-aiohttp.html for an exposition of various approaches based on Python.

The immediate error message indicates that you have DOS carriage returns in your input file; this is a common FAQ which is covered very well over at [Are shell scripts sensitive to encoding and line endings?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39527571/are-shell-scripts-sensitive-to-encoding-and-line-endings)

You can run multiple `curl` instances in parallel but you will probably eventually saturate your network -- experiment with various degrees of parallelism -- maybe split up your file into smaller pieces and run each piece on a separate host with a separate network connection (perhaps in the cloud) but to quickly demonstrate,

```
tr -d '\r' <file |
xargs -P 256 -i sh -c 'curl -Is {} | grep Location'
```

to run 256 instances of `curl` in parallel. You will still need to figure out which output corresponds to which input, so maybe refactor to something like

```
tr -d '\r' <file |
xargs -P 256 -i sh -c 'curl -Is {} | sed -n "s/Location/{}:&/p"'
```

to print the input domain name in front of each output.

(Maybe also note that just a domain name is not a complete URL. `curl` will helpfully attempt to add a "http://" in front and then connect to that, but that still doesn't give you an accurate result if the domain only has a "https://" website and no redirect from the http:// one.)

If you are on a Mac, where `xargs` doesn't understand `-i`, try `-I {}` or something like

```
tr -d '\r' <file |
xargs -P 256 sh -c 'for url; do curl -Is "$url" | sed -n "s/Location/{}:&/p"; done' _
```

The examples assume you didn't already fix the DOS carriage returns once and for all; you probably really should (and consider dropping Windows from the equation entirely).